# Does WCF windows service support intranet connection?

Tags: c#, wcf, intranet

I'm a beginner of WCF. I tried to host my WCF server in IIS and can succeed to visit the service in another machine. When I change to host this WCF server in Windows Service, I can visit in local, but failed in another machine. Does WCF support this? If there is any example to demo how to use windows service hosted WCF in Intranet, that will be appreciated!

I have closed firewall on both machines.
Below is the service config I used:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Service" name="TestService.Test">
      <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="basic" contract="TestService.ITest">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/TestService/"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Service">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

@Rahul, thanks your help. Finally I succeed. Here I paste my configuration, hope can help someone who meet similar problem. 
Change my server config to:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="tcpConfig">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Service" name="TestService.Test">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8081/Test" binding="netTcpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="tcpConfig" name="tcp" contract="TestService.ITest" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/TestService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Service">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And below is my client config, which run on another machine:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="tcp">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.168.209.132:8081/TestService" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="tcp" contract="TestServiceReference.ITest"
            name="tcp" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: check your firewall settings and confiurations, also dont run it in a service first, make a test app and see if it runs from there it will be easier to debug, this is called reducing the degrees of freedom

Comment: Either way if you can access it locally and not from another computer, this seems very suspicious, and very firewallish or network related

Comment: @MichaelRandall, that won't be the case since he can access it when deployed in IIS

Comment: It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's intranet service and if you choose to deploy as windows service then consider using `netTcpBinding` like

```
binding="netTcpBinding"
```

Also, consider using proper IPv4 address of your machine rather than `localhost`